# New routes overriding previously instantiated

Tags: ruby, rack, rackup

I must be missing something from Rack's [non-existant](http://rack.github.com/) docs :) I'm trying to add additional webservice routes to [ruhoh](https://github.com/ruhoh), and can get them to work at `localhost:9292/test`, but the new `Rack::Builder` object seems to override the last, as I can no longer access the default blog at `localhost:9292/`. I've tried different ways of defining the new routes without declaring `Rack::Builder.new`, but can't get anything to work.

What is the best way to add additional routes using this interface?

```
require 'rack'
require 'ruhoh'

run Ruhoh::Program.preview

# Additional routes

builder = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::CommonLogger
  map '/test' do
    run Proc.new {|env| [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},  StringIO.new("infinity 0.1")] }
  end
end

run builder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the way you use it, `run Ruhoh::Program.preview` will never serve requests.

You should put it into builder:

```
builder = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::CommonLogger
  map '/' do
    run Ruhoh::Program.preview
  end

  map '/test' do
    run Proc.new {|env| [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},  StringIO.new("infinity 0.1")] }
  end
end

run builder
```

Comment: I should mention that for ruhoh users, this loses the static asset routes. That's another issue, though :)